# RactiveJS and time conditional DOM

Tags: javascript, json, ractivejs

I have page wich displays  time-dependent text-snippets from a json with Ractive.js.
After initialisation, I want to check every minute, if the stop-time, which is stored in the json, is due. Then the text-snippet should be hidden.

Things I've  tried:

```
{{#if time_due > Date.time()}}
do whatever
{{/if}}
```

The above doesn't work for me. 
I also played around with computed properties of Ractive.js, but that didn't work either.
Has somebody a good idea and/or can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ractive won't recompute expressions (like `time_due > Date.now()`) unless it thinks something has changed. The easy solution is to assign the current time to a data property and update it periodically:

```js
var ractive = new Ractive({
  el: 'main',
  template: '#template',
  data: {
    timeNow: Date.now(),
    displayUntil: Date.now() + 5000
  }
});

setInterval( function () {
  ractive.set( 'timeNow', Date.now() );
}, 500 );
```

```html
<script src='http://cdn.ractivejs.org/edge/ractive.js'></script>

<main></main>

<script id='template' tyle='text/html'>
  {{#if timeNow < displayUntil}}
    <p>now you see me</p>
  {{else}}
    <p>now you don't</p>
  {{/if}}
  
  <p>(time remaining: {{displayUntil - timeNow}}ms)</p>
</script>
```

Comment: Nice and clean. Thank you!